# How to open a JS file in a new tab and close after 2 second

Tags: javascript

I am trying to load a `js` file on a new tab and once it is loaded then close that tab. Maybe after 2 second. The reason behind this is, my client don't want to clear the cache all the time I am deploying something. So he want a button to clear the cache automatically instead of clearing the cache from browser. The library I am using is storing to many cache. So I did lots of try and none of those helped me such.
One way I had tried adding the version after `js` file name. like this. `file.js?v=1.11` but it did not helped. So final thing I realized that only loading the `js` file might help me. So I am trying to add an `a` tag where link of that `js` file will be attached and on clicking the link that `js` file will be opened on a new tab. This part is working fine. Here is the code to open the js file in new tab.

```
<a href="/js/file.js" target="__BLANK">load cache file</a>
```

Now what I want to do is, I want to close that new tab after few second. For this I have added this line of code,

```
setTimeout(window.close(), 2000);
```

But this part of the code is not working. I mean tab is not getting closed after 2 second. Can you please guide me where I am doing wrong on above code. Thank you.

Comment: Don't think you can from the original window. The one you open would have to be an html file which can run JS and close itself. This is definitely not the right way to clear the cache either. Are you running a service worker? `file.js?v=1.11` should have worked as long as the number correctly changed

Comment: Sorry to say I did not got your this point `The one you open would have to be an html file which can run JS and close itself`. And I am not using any service worker. File is stored into same server and the server is aptible.

Answer (score 0):

Link to another page. Add this script in at the top of the page you link to:This might help you

```
<script type="text/javascript">
setTimeout(
 function ( )
 {
  self.close();
  }, 5000 );
</script>
```